# Laravel - How to return last value from user input into a view

Tags: laravel

I'm building a backend for my website in Laravel. I need only few text boxes to populate a template. So far I've managed to do that, but every time I pass a value to a template I see also all previous values, not only the last one.

So for example if I'm editing slider title, I see also all previous slider titles - I want to see only last one.

My controler:

```
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::all();

    homepage::create([
        'slider_title' => $input['slider_title'],
    ]);

    return Redirect::to('/');
}
```

Part of view responsible for displaying slider title:

```
@foreach ($homepage as $home)
    {{$home->slider_title}}
@endforeach
```

View for user input in admin:

```
{{ Form::open(['url' => '/admin']) }}
<div>
    {{ Form::label('slider_title', 'Slider title:') }}
    {{ Form::text('slider_title') }}
</div>

<div>
    {{ Form::submit('Change a slider title') }}
</div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Route for admin:

```
Route::post('/admin', 'AdminController@store');
```

Route for main page:

```
Route::get('/', 'PageController@home');
```

PageController home method:

```
 public function home()
  {
    $homepage = Homepage::all();
    return View::make('home')->with('homepage',$homepage);
  }
```

I tried changing PageControl with:

```
$homepage = Homepage::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
```

but I'm getting this error:

ErrorException: **Trying to get property of non-object** on my view page

```
public function home()
  {
    $homepage = Homepage::all();
    return View::make('home')->with('homepage',$homepage);
  }
```

Comment: Can you add the code for the method that calls that view ?

Comment: @lagbox I've added routes for admin and main page

Comment: sorry for late response ... can you post the code for the PageController@home method ?  I just want to see how you are passing that $homepage to the view.

Comment: @lagbox I've added PageController@home method. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: `Homepage::all()` will return all items in your database. Is this not the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing all slides because you are selecting all of them:

```
$homepage = Homepage::all();
```

This should give you the last one:

```
$homepage = Homepage::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
```

or

```
$homepage = Homepage::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
```

Remember that now you are getting only one result and you cannot use foreach anymore:

```
foreach ($homepage as $home)
```

You can refer to it directly:

```
$homepage->slider_title
```

If you still want to return an array to use foreach, this is an option:

```
$homepage = array( Homepage::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first() );
```

Comment: Thank you Antonio. I was trying already something like this. I'm getting ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object in my view: <?php foreach ($homepage as $home): ?>
          <?php echo $home->slider_title; ?> 
          <?php endforeach; ?>  And this is confusing me all the time

Comment: Yeah, now you have only one result, so you cannot use foreach anymore. Edited to show.

Comment: Thank you so much for opening my noob eyes :) appreciate it